# Insert /Update in Many to one relations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

**1.Layout.java**

```
@Entity
Public class Layout 
{
private int layoutId;    ---- primaary key autoincrement
private String layoutName;

@OneToMany( mappedBy = "layout" ,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true )
private List<LayoutDetails> layoutdetails;
}
```

**2.LayoutDetail.java**

```
@Entity
public class LayoutDetail
{
private int layoutdetailid; ---- primaary key autoincrement

private String columnName;

@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade= {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "layoutid")
private Layout layout;



}
```

Is There any way i can insert and update only in  LayoutDetail?

I tried to do this in usual way but it says  layoutid cannot be null , insert fails

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and it worked fine. I could create and update individually in both classes.

The only change I made (based on the code you have shared) was using the `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue` annotations for the entities.